# Get specific word count in particular column by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have to get the count of specific word from the column in the table.

Example : assume this value is in the column:

```
uid-234,uid-342,uid-345
```

I need to retrieve the count as **3** by using T-SQL in SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean by _word_? `uid-234` is word?

Comment: This is a **horribly bad design** - you should ***never ever*** put multiple values into a single column! This violates the **first normal form** of database design and will cause you endless grief down the road. Fix your design first !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code

```
select 
    *, (select count(*) from dbo.Split(concatenatedColumn,',')) cnt
from myTable
```

But you need to create the [user defined function SPLIT string](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx) on your database first

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It should work

```
SELECT SUM(len(YourColumn) - len(replace(YourColumn, ',', '')) +1) 
    AS TotalCount
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(100) = 'uid-234,uid-342,uid-345'

SELECT len(@Column) - len(replace(@Column, ',', '')) + 1 AS TotalCount
```